# Assigning a method to UITextField in code

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have a textfield at the bottom of my view.  When you click to edit it, the keyboard covers it up and you can't see what you are typing.  I want to make a method that will readjust the view whenever this textfield is being edited.

If I had the textfield declared through the interface builder, then I know all I would have to do would be to link (ctrl click then drag) it.  But I have the textfield declared in code, so I am wondering how to assign a method to it.

pseudo code of what I would like to do:

```
if (the text field is currently being edited){
    call method: adjust view
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the UITextFieldDelegate in your .h like so:

`@interface ShippingInfoViewController : UIViewController < UITextFieldDelegate>`

and make sure to set your textField's delegate to `self`

Then you have access to many methods, such as

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {`

`-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{`

`-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{`

`- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {`

and many others.

[apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Comment: in my .h file I have my interface declared as follows

`@interface SecondDetailViewController : UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>`

when i set the the textfield's delegate to itself it crashes at run time, any ideas ?

Comment: How are you doing it? is the textfield in storyboards or in code? I usually do it in storyboards by control clicking (or right clicking) from the field to the file owner (the yellow box at the bottom) and selecting delegate.  in code it should just be `textField.delegate = self;`

Comment: I found the problem; I was setting the delegate before I was allocating.  Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the text field, set its delegate to self.

```
[textField setDelegate:self];
```

then implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //adjust view here
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //move view back to correct position here
}
```

You can also register for UIKeyboardWillShow/UIKeyboardWillHide or UIKeyboardDidShow/UIKeyboardDidHide messages and implement functions for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a delegate to the text view:

```
[textView setDelegate: self]
```

where I assume, that `self` is your view controller, which needs to conform to the [`UITextViewDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextViewDelegate). The text view will call `textViewShouldBeginEditing:`/`textViewWillBeginEditing` whenever it starts its editing cycle.

Comment: @user1458968 Which is very true; but how would I know that? My answer was the first one :-) Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following functions :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{  
  [self moveTextViewForKeyboard:notification up:YES];
}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self moveTextViewForKeyboard:notification up:NO];
}


- (void)moveTextViewForKeyboard:(NSNotification*)notification up:(BOOL)up {
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
   NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
   UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
   CGRect keyboardRect;

  [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
  animationDuration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
  keyboardRect = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

 if (up == YES) {
    CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
    CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.noteTextView.frame;
    originalTextViewFrame = self.noteTextView.frame;
    newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop - self.noteTextView.frame.origin.y - 10;

    self.noteTextView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
 } else {
    // Keyboard is going away (down) - restore original frame
    self.noteTextView.frame = originalTextViewFrame;
 }

  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Use static variable for originalTextViewFrame :

```
static CGRect originalTextViewFrame;
```